# jQuery show unique popup for each link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a series of links on my page, each link has a unique id: `library_vid_link-UNIQUE_ID`. When clicked, I want to show a popup which shows information unique to that link.

For each link, I have a hidden popup, which, when clicked, the popup is displayed. The popup also has a unique id: `less_preview_popup-UNIQUE_ID` (the unique id for the link and popup both match).

Here is a sample of my html code:

```
<a href="#" class="library_vid_link" id="library_vid_link-801">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO
</a>

<div class="lesson_preview_popup" id="lesson_preview_popup-801">
    THIS IS THE POPUP
</div>

<a href="#" class="library_vid_link" id="library_vid_link-802">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO
</a>

<div class="lesson_preview_popup" id="lesson_preview_popup-802">
    THIS IS THE POPUP 2
</div>
```

Here is the jquery i'm currently using:

```
jQuery('.library_vid_link').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.lesson_preview_popup').css('top', '25%');
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll'); 
});
```

The issue I'm having is that when I click on a link, ALL the popups show, not just the one that relates to the link clicked. Is there a way to target the popup that belongs to the link clicked?

Comment: The popup element alway is after link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the data-attribute:

```
<a data-popup="lesson_preview_popup_801" ....
```

And

```
$("#"+$(this).data("popup")).show().css('top', '25%');
```

Using `$(this).next()` instead, assumes that the div to show is the next sibling of the link

Comment: There is better solution instead adding new attribute.

Comment: However adding the data attribute is safer than using .next()

Comment: Yep I like this answer - nice and simple, does exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('.lesson_preview_popup').css('top', '25%');
```

into this:

```
$(this).next().css('top', '25%');
```

**Alternatively**, save the ID (e.g. 801) in a new attribute, like this:

```
<a data-id="801" ...
```

Then, call the popup like this:

```
jQuery('.library_vid_link').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var thisId = $(this).attr("data-id"); //get "801"
    $('#lesson_preview_popup-' + thisId).css('top', '25%'); //construct the ID and call the popup by its ID
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll'); 
});
```

Comment: That assumes the div is the next sibling. Using data-attribute is what I suggested too

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) select next sibling of element. Use it like bottom example

```
$('.library_vid_link').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().show().css('top', '25%');
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll'); 
});
```

```js
$('.library_vid_link').click(function( event ) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().show().css('top', '25%');
    //$('body').addClass('no-scroll'); 
});
```

```css
.lesson_preview_popup {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="library_vid_link" id="library_vid_link-801">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO
</a>
<div class="lesson_preview_popup" id="lesson_preview_popup-801">
    THIS IS THE POPUP
</div>
<a href="#" class="library_vid_link" id="library_vid_link-802">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO
</a>
<div class="lesson_preview_popup" id="lesson_preview_popup-802">
    THIS IS THE POPUP 2
</div>
```

Comment: Already suggested and for this to work, the div has to be the next sibling of the link